# Star WebPRNT cash drawer

Tags: javascript, thermal-printer

I tried to contact Star directly but got no answer to my question just yet.

I use the Star WebPRNT & JS library in combination with a MPOP to print receipts. All works well but i can't figure out how to open the cash drawer from de Star WebPRNT browser. The other SDK's for iOS and Android (or JAVA) have options to open (or kick) the cash drawer.

The JS SDK has a function called: onCashDrawerOpen() but this is only a listener. There is no out of the box function to open the cash drawer. Or i can't find it?
[Webprint extension manual JS SDK](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/en/_StarWebPrintExtManager-js.htm#onCashDrawerOpen)

I tried to use their own example scripts but there is no 'open cash drawer' example:
[Example Scripts](http://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/sdk_webprnt/sample/A001.html)

Even tried to search for a build in function that would open the cash drawer after print but i can't something like that either.

Hopefully anyone can push me in to the right direction.

Comment: Solution found...

Comment: What was the solution you found?

Comment: Star MPOP has a buildin cash drawer. So you can call the "createPeripheralElement" command from the manual to open it. "var request = builder.createPeripheralElement({channel:1, on:200, off:200});"

Comment: Where did you find the manual? Or was it a physical manual?

Comment: I found this documentation: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/en/_StarWebPrintBuilder-js.htm#createPeripheralElement Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Joey, I can't find any method to open cash drawer with iOS SDK, could you please share a document link or code snippet about that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @L_K Not sure how the IOS SDK works for Star mPOP. I only worked with the JS SDK. But the cashdrawer methods in the JS SDK are called: Peripheral Elements. Maby it helps you find your function in the IOS SDK. I found an cashdrawer function on their github: https://github.com/star-micronics/StarPRNT-SDK-iOS-Swift/blob/013efbf1de71565a16ca938f227129576ac56948/SDK/Swift%20SDK/CashDrawerViewController.swift